# Change Color According to a Location

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, color, geometry

So I basically ask for points of this cube to color according to their distance for the origin. So if the color ramp is black to the white furthest point should be black and the closest one must be white. Is there a way for me to colorize the object this way? I also want to change its location so it needs to be updating its data live. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible but I am not entirely sure what exactly are you looking for... you can use a spherical gradient like this and this could be your starting base... use some plane as a reference object while using it on the more complex objects like this cube:

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Just to add, you can control the gradient spread and position using the *Math > Multiply Add* node https://imgur.com/a/U5vPjxg (click image to play the gif)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **Grading Texture** in the shader editor with set to *spherical*.
For an indipendant center set the **Texture Coordinate** to *Object* and use another object as reference.